# Why aren't liters a SI Unit? And why isn't there a unit for volume?

Tags: units, si-units, volume, metrology

In the International System of Units, there is the **second** for time, the **metre** for length, the **kilogram** for mass, the **ampere** for electric current, the **kelvin** for temperature, the **mole** for density, and the **candela** for luminous intensity. Why do we square the length unit for area, and cube it for volume? Why isn't the liter an official international unit (it very much is unoficially)? And why don't we have an area unit?

Comment: Read section *4 Non-SI units that are accepted for use with the SI*, page 145 - , of [The International System of Units](https://www.bipm.org/documents/20126/41483022/SI-Brochure-9-EN.pdf)

Answer (score 5):

The ISU (or, more often, just SI) only lists *fundamental* units (base units). All the rest of the quantities are derived from it by combining them, for example area is length squared and volume is length cubic. But other examples include force (mass times length divided by seconds squared), energy (force times length), and so on.

Thus volume (length cubic) is expressed in SI-units as $m^3$ (cubic meters). Liter is not part of SI at all, but can be "converted" to SI-based units via the equivalence $1 \; L = 1 \;dm^3 = 10^{-3} \; m^3$. The fact that it is commonly used does not mean it is "fundamental": in the end, volume is just a length cubed. In the SI we use $m^3$ but that does not prevent you, in specific conditions, to use the liter given the above conversion (same goes for area of course: you can use $m^2$ but also acres or whatever).

Yet another example: velocity for cars is commonly computed in $km/h$ or $mph$ [miles per hour], but the SI-derived unit would be $m/s$ (meters per second), i.e. length/time in SI units.